# plugin problem w/ mp3 and videos

Tags: plugins

When I try to play a movie or a song on my computer (not online), I get a message saying I need to install a plugin.

How can I install this plugin or to play media ?

Comment: please add more details, like version of Ubuntu and what program you try to play the media.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this issue.

1. Install the media codecs needed
   One approach will be to install the necessary codecs you need, and you can do the same by running the following command in terminal (by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

   > sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
2. Install another media player like VLC
   VLC is an excellent free and open source media player and supports all codecs. To install, simply start the terminal (by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and you use the following command:

   > sudo apt-get install vlc